# OpenLayers 3 WMS GetFeatureInfo popup

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers, getfeatureinfo

I have a map a at the link below:

http://gis.xyz/openlayers/openlayer.html

I added one of my GeoServer WMS layers to the map, now I try to add the attributes window pop up on click. I found to examples on the OpenLayers 3 homepage, but I cannot put together a working code...

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/popup.html?q=popup

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html?q=popup

Is there any chance to have a working sample somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to [following](http://astuntechnology.github.io/osgis-ol3-leaflet/ol3/05-WMS-INFO.html) tutorial to figure out how to get popups on WMS and WFS layers. Maybe it will be useful to you.

Here is some of the relevant code

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {

// Hide existing popup and reset it's offset
popup.hide();
popup.setOffset([0, 0]);

// Attempt to find a marker from the planningAppsLayer
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
});

if (feature) {

    var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var props = feature.getProperties();
    var info = "<h2><a href='" + props.caseurl + "'>" + props.casereference + "</a></h2>";
        info += "<p>" + props.locationtext + "</p>";
        info += "<p>Status: " + props.status + " " + props.statusdesc + "</p>";
    // Offset the popup so it points at the middle of the marker not the tip
    popup.setOffset([0, -22]);
    popup.show(coord, info);

} else {
    // skip the forEachFeatureAtPixel if your map is generated via WMS
    var url = districtLayer
                .getSource()
                .getFeatureInfoUrl(
                    evt.coordinate,
                    map.getView().getResolution(),
                    map.getView().getProjection(),
                    {
                        'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                        'propertyName': 'NAME,AREA_CODE,DESCRIPTIO'
                    }
                );

    reqwest({
        url: url,
        type: 'json',
    }).then(function (data) {
        var feature = data.features[0];
        var props = feature.properties;
        var info = "<h2>" + props.NAME + "</h2><p>" + props.DESCRIPTIO + "</p>";
        popup.show(evt.coordinate, info);
    });

}});
```

Comment: The link is really helpful, and this will be the solution, however I cannot make it work because of a "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" issue...

Comment: Does the error message say anything about Cross Origin Request Sharing?

Comment: I solved this issue, I moved the html file to geoserver root directory

Comment: Anyone who tested this code on openlayers 5?